# mongodump and mongorestore with SSL

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongodump

**Getting `mongodump` and `mongorestore` work with security quite troublesome.**

I have `mongod` v3.4.1 with `requireSSL` running at `192.168.99.100`. It is IP address of VirtualBox docker machine running on my Windows. It is just for testing of-cause.

The instance already configured to use TLS/SSL both server and client signed with the same CA. I use the IP address for `mongod` Common Name to allow hostname validation. The authentication already enabled to accept my client certificate.

So everything is working. I can connect to it like this:

```
mongo --ssl --host 192.168.99.100 --sslCAFile rootCA.pem --sslPEMKeyFile me.pem
```

but now I can't get both `mongodump` and `mongorestore` working:

```
mongodump --ssl --host 192.168.99.100 --sslCAFile rootCA.pem --sslPEMKeyFile me.pem -d olddb
mongorestore --ssl --host 192.168.99.100 --sslCAFile rootCA.pem --sslPEMKeyFile me.pem -d newdb --dir=dump/olddb
```

Both return this error:

```
2017-01-13T04:28:03.881+0800    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers, openssl error: Host validation error
```

I have been trying to turn off client certificate, use username/password but still did not work. I need to remove the SSL in order to make it work.

**That means I can only use `preferSSL` in production.**
There is no way to bypass SSL in localhost if I stick with `requireSSL`.

Anyone getting the same error? Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 9):

Add this option to the command-line:

> --sslAllowInvalidHostnames

Full connection sample:

> mongo --host 192.168.99.100 --username luke
>   --password skywalker --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --sslCAFile rootCA.pem --sslPEMKeyFile me.pem --sslAllowInvalidHostnames

Answer (score 1):

First check your logs at path /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Also there is default path of SSL Certificates. And for unix based systems given an SSL certificate located at /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem

As per my understanding for this problem, i would say certificate path needs to be checked. SSL certificate is not located in your windows environment. Try adding full path of certificate.
Also look into this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/

Happy coding